# Get unique object base on attribute from the NSMutableArray that contain object of User class

Tags: ios, iphone

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * user_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * group_id;
@end
```

`NSMutableArray` contain set of object of type User class
I want to retrieve unique object base on attribute `user_name`
Means I want to prevent repeated `user_name`

---

```
NSMutableArray *arrayBikePartsFiltering = [NSMutableArray new];

arrayAsFoundSubPart = @[@{
                           partid:12,
                           name : @"Silencer"
                          },
                          @{
                           partid:11,
                           name : @"Gear"
                           },
                          @{
                               partid:13,
                               name : @"Break"
                           },
                          @{
                               partid:12,
                               name : @“Silencer”
                           },];

        for (BikeParts *subPart in arrayAsFoundSubPart) {
            
            BOOL isFound = NO;
            for (BikeParts *subPartl2 in array BikeParts Filtering) {
                if ([[subPartl2.part_id stringValue] isEqualToString:[subPart.part_id stringValue]]) {
                    isFound = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isFound) {
                [arrayBikePartsFiltering addObject:subPart];
            }
            
        }
```

As per above array i want to `partid=12` and `name="silencer"` only once 
result array that i want:

```
arrayAsFoundSubPart = @[@{
                           partid:12,
                           name : @"Silencer"
                          },
                          @{
                           partid:11,
                           name : @"Gear"
                           },
                          @{
                               partid:13,
                               name : @"Break"
                           }
                          ];
```

Comment: filter your array with a predicate !

Comment: Pls, refer edited question, what exactly i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

NSSet is what you need
You may use NSOrderedSet to preserve order:

```
NSOrderedSet* set = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:arrayAsFoundSubPart];
```

This will give you a set of *completely* unique objects;

If you're using custom classes, you should implement `isEqual` method to compare objects (e.g. by Id):

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(BikeParts*)object {
  return ([object isKindOfClass:[BikeParts class]] && [object.name isEqual:self.name]);
}
```

Resulting set will contain ordered sequence of unique objects.

Alternatively you may cycle through the array and assign values to a Dictionary by id:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (BikeParts *subPart in arrayAsFoundSubPart) {
  //if (!dict[subPart.name])
    dict[subPart.name] = subPart;
}
```

result will be in `dict.allValues`

edited: filtering by name instead of by id